Adding Row and Column Vectors
How do you evaluate
$$
(\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla )\mathbf{v} + \mathbf{v} (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v})
$$
I saw this as an expansion of $\nabla \cdot (\mathbf{v} \otimes \mathbf{v})$ but is this correct?
From trying to work this out the first term is a row vector (1x3 matrix) and the second is a column vector (3x1 matrix).
Since the two terms are still vectors can they still be added or is this just a nonsensical expression?

I'm not up on this, but aren't $
(\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla )$ and $ (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v})
$ scalars, so you're adding scalar multiples of $\mathbf v$?

Supposing $\mathbf v$ is a column vector, why would the first term be a row vector? since $\mathbf v\cdot \nabla$ is a scalar differential operator (that applies to each coordinate) and and $\nabla \cdot \mathbf v$ is a scalar, both terms in your expression are the same dimensions. Did you perhaps not recognize the scalar (inner) product?

@rafilou2003 $\nabla \mathbf{v}$ is a rank-2 tensor, so shouldn't $(\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{v}$ produce a vector?

You wrote $\nabla \cdot \mathbf v$ which I assumed to be $div(\mathbf v)$, which would have been a scalar. In the same vein, if you write $\mathbf v = (v_x,v_y,v_z)$, I understood $\mathbf v \cdot \nabla$ as the differential operator $v_x\partial_x + v_y\partial_y + v_z\partial_z$.

$$\mathbf{v}\equiv\left(\begin{array}{c}
v_x\\
v_y\\
v_z
\end{array}\right),\ \ \ \nabla\equiv grad(\ .\ )\equiv\left(\begin{array}{c}
\frac d{dx}\\
\frac d{dy}\\
\frac d{dz}
\end{array}\right)
$$
$$
(\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla )\mathbf{v} + \mathbf{v} (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v})
=
(v_x\,\frac d{dx}+v_y\,\frac d{dy}+v_z\,\frac d{dz})\,\mathbf{v} + 
\mathbf{v}\, (\frac d{dx}\,v_x+\frac d{dy}\,v_y+\frac d{dz}\,v_z)
$$
$$=\left(\begin{array}{c}
v_x\,\frac {d\,v_x}{dx}+v_y\,\frac {d\,v_x}{dy}+v_z\,\frac {d\,v_x}{dz}+
v_x\,\frac {d\,v_x}{dx}+v_x\,\frac {d\,v_y}{dy}+v_x\,\frac {d\,v_z}{dz}\\
v_x\,\frac {d\,v_y}{dx}+v_y\,\frac {d\,v_y}{dy}+v_z\,\frac {d\,v_y}{dz}+
v_y\,\frac {d\,v_x}{dx}+v_y\,\frac {d\,v_y}{dy}+v_y\,\frac {d\,v_z}{dz}\\
v_x\,\frac {d\,v_z}{dx}+v_y\,\frac {d\,v_z}{dy}+v_z\,\frac {d\,v_z}{dz}+
v_z\,\frac {d\,v_x}{dx}+v_z\,\frac {d\,v_y}{dy}+v_z\,\frac {d\,v_z}{dz}
\end{array}\right)$$
$$=\left(\begin{array}{c}
2\,v_x\,\frac {d\,v_x}{dx}+\left(v_y\,\frac {d\,v_x}{dy}+v_x\,\frac {d\,v_y}{dy}\right)+\left(v_z\,\frac {d\,v_x}{dz}
+v_x\,\frac {d\,v_z}{dz}\right)\\
\left(v_x\,\frac {d\,v_y}{dx}+v_y\,\frac {d\,v_x}{dx}\right)+2\,v_y\,\frac {d\,v_y}{dy}+\left(v_z\,\frac {d\,v_y}{dz}+
v_y\,\frac {d\,v_z}{dz}\right)\\
\left(v_x\,\frac {d\,v_z}{dx}+v_z\,\frac {d\,v_x}{dx}\right)+\left(v_y\,\frac {d\,v_z}{dy}+v_z\,\frac {d\,v_y}{dy}\right)+2\,v_z\,\frac {d\,v_z}{dz}
\end{array}\right)$$
$$=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\frac d{dx}(v_x\,v_x)+\frac d{dy}(v_y\,v_x)+\frac d{dz}(v_z\,v_x)\\
\frac d{dx}(v_x\,v_y)+\frac d{dy}(v_y\,v_y)+\frac d{dz}(v_z\,v_y)\\
\frac d{dx}(v_x\,v_z)+\frac d{dy}(v_y\,v_z)+\frac d{dz}(v_z\,v_z)
\end{array}\right)$$
$$=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\frac d{dx}\\
\frac d{dy}\\
\frac d{dz}
\end{array}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
v_x\,v_x & v_y\,v_x & v_z\,v_x\\
v_x\,v_y & v_y\,v_y & v_z\,v_y\\
v_x\,v_z & v_y\,v_z & v_z\,v_z
\end{array}\right)
=\nabla \cdot (\mathbf{v} \otimes \mathbf{v})$$
--- rk

Looking at two dimensions is sufficient.
The only way I can make sense of this is
\begin{align}
&\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{v}\otimes\mathbf{v})=\pmatrix{\partial_x&\partial_y}\cdot\pmatrix{v_1v_1& v_1v_2\\v_2v_1&v_2v_2}=
\pmatrix{\partial_x(v_1v_1)+\partial_y(v_2v_1)\\\partial_x(v_1v_2)+\partial_y(v_2v_2)}
\\[2mm]
&=\pmatrix{v_1\,\partial_xv_1+v_1\,\partial_xv_1+v_1\,\partial_yv_2+v_2\,\partial_yv_1\\
v_1\,\partial_xv_2+v_2\,\partial_xv_1+v_2\,\partial_yv_2+v_2\,\partial_yv_2}\\[2mm]
&=\pmatrix{v_1\,\partial_xv_1+v_2\,\partial_yv_1\\
v_1\,\partial_xv_2+v_2\,\partial_yv_2}+
\pmatrix{v_1\,\partial_xv_1+v_1\,\partial_yv_2\\
v_2\,\partial_xv_1+v_2\,\partial_yv_2}\\[2mm]
&=(\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla)\pmatrix{v_1\\v_2}+\pmatrix{v_1\\v_2}(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v})\,.
\end{align}
This can be written as
$$
(\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{v}(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v})
$$
or as
$$
(\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{v}+(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v})\mathbf{v}\,.
$$
